# Unable to add meta_query to woocommerce_product_query

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to add my custom `meta_query` to WooCommerce main query using the `woocommerce_product_query` hook.

I tried this code:

```
function testing_woo_product_query( $q ){ 
    $args = array(
      'relation' => 'AND',
      array(
        'meta_key'  => '_price',
        'value'     => 10,
        'compare'   => '>=',
      ),
      array(
        'meta_key'  => '_price',
        'value'     => 30,
        'compare'   => '<=',
      )
    );
    
    $q->set( 'meta_query', $args ); 

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'testing_woo_product_query' );
```

But the code doesn't work. Can anybody tell me where is the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your Meta Query should use `key` and not `meta_key` - also you can use `"between => array (low number, high number)`.  You can see the proper format here [WP Function Reference meta_query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_meta_query/#comment-1988)

This will do what you are trying to do above:

```
function testing_woo_product_query( $q ){ 
    $args = array(
      array(
        'key'       => '_price',
        'value'     => array( 10 , 30 ),
        'compare'   => 'BETWEEN',
        'type'      => 'numeric'  
      ),
    );

    $q->set( 'meta_query', $args );

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'testing_woo_product_query' );
```

Be warned though, that this will effect shop and archive / category pages unless you qualify your function with specific details.